# How can i call sagemaker inference endpoint using API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to call sagemaker inference endpoint from api gateway with AWS Integration.I don't want to use lamdba in between of API gateway and sagemaker runtime. I followed this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html) to setup api gateway method but it fails.

How can i call sagemaker inference endpoint from API gateway?

Web Browser ----> API Gateway ----> Sagemaker endpoint

Comment: Have you tried this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/ ?

Comment: it uses lambda in between of api gateway and sagemaker.

Comment: You have to use the Lambda in the middle as the Lambda function is the one that is getting the permission to call the SageMaker endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

API Gateway supports integration with AWS services directly (without the Lambda). You can follow the instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html.

When you go to Step 4 in the instructions above, for the AWS Service option, you can choose 'SageMaker Runtime' to target the invoke endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

API Gateway can be used to front an Amazon SageMaker inference endpoint as a REST API, by making use of an API Gateway feature called mapping templates. This feature makes it possible for the REST API to be integrated directly with an Amazon SageMaker runtime endpoint, thereby avoiding the use of any intermediate compute resource (such as AWS Lambda or Amazon ECS containers) to invoke the endpoint. The result is a solution that is simpler, faster, and cheaper to run. See this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-machine-learning-powered-rest-api-with-amazon-api-gateway-mapping-templates-and-amazon-sagemaker/) for more detail on how to configure the API Gateway mapping templates against the Sagemaker runtime endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

it's a long shot since it's an old question but somebody might end up here.

Reading the first section of the documentation about calling the inference endpoint in sagemaker, you'll find that you can only call it with a POST and pass your input data in the body.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html

So it might be that you created a GET method in API Gateway and that you need to map your request parameters to a body payload or simply set up a POST method instead.